# CSV - Converting SOME Columns to Rows with duplicated data

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am working with an unresponsive vendor whose CSV files for inventory are completely unsearcheable by Excel. My team has no knowledge or use of Unix, but I know that a simple IF loop or two with `awk` or `sed` will fix my problem.

The raw file comes to me like this:

```
Col1 Col2    ... Col8 ..... Col30 Col31 .. Col30+N
---------------------
UPC MasterSKU ...  UnitCost ..... AltSKU1 AltSKU2 .. AltSKU_N
```

Some MasterSKUs have only a few AltSKUs, some have as many as 318. This maximum number can change monthly!

Example:

```
UPC MasterSKU  Cost AltSKU1 AltSKU2 .... AltSKU_N
------------------------------------------------------
10000001  ABC  $5.00  ABC01 ABC001 ABC1
10000002  BCD  $2.34  BCD01 BCD.go BD.c.2 ...200 AltSKUs later... BDDCD7
```

Since my team needs Excel and the search algorithms are limited there, I need All AltSKUs listed in a single column and a cost next to them.

This is what I hope to get as an output:

```
UPC MasterSKU  Cost AltSKU
--------------------------
10000001  ABC  $5.00  ABC01
10000001  ABC  $5.00  ABC001
10000001  ABC  $5.00  ABC1
10000002  BCD  $2.34  BCD01
10000002  BCD  $2.34  BCD.go
10000002  BCD  $2.34  BCD01

 ... repeat for 200 AltSKUs

10000002  BCD  $2.34  BDDCD7
```

NOTE: what happened to the ABC MasterSKU. Since there are only 3 AltSKUs, there are only 3 lines. There are not 315 blank AltSKUs after the first 3 non-blank AltSKUs

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that in awk would be like:

#### Code:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=4; i <= NF; i++) print $1, $2, $3, $i }' file1
```

#### file1:

```
10000001 ABC $5.00 ABC01 ABC001 ABC1
10000002 BCD $2.34 BCD01 BCD.go BD.c.2 BDDCD7
```

#### Results:

```
10000001 ABC $5.00 ABC01
10000001 ABC $5.00 ABC001
10000001 ABC $5.00 ABC1
10000002 BCD $2.34 BCD01
10000002 BCD $2.34 BCD.go
10000002 BCD $2.34 BD.c.2
10000002 BCD $2.34 BDDCD7
```

Comment: I am upvoting this because it got me started, but it's missing a key ingredient. This ignores the fact that the raw file is CSV that is 318 fields long, so I'm getting 318 lines returned for every row. My initial file is a few thousand rows, and I'm generating over 1.3MM lines of output, most of which are just useless blanks.

My best answer so far is as follows, but it's not formatting the output properly at the end of a section. I think my syntax is messing things up.

`$ nawk -F, '{ for (i=30; i<=NF; i++); if($i=="\"\"") i++; print $2 FS $i FS $3 FS $8;}' File1.csv`

Comment: I am sorry this answer did not meet your needs, but the missing key ingredient is sample data which is formatted differently than you have shown in your question. The code above prints no extra (blank) lines for the data format given in the question. In the future it would be helpful if you showed the actual data format.  If asking for a house to be painted green, it should not be surprising when the painted house is green, and not the hoped for red.  Cheers.